# Unity: how to read CSV file in android external path?

Tags: c#, android, csv, unity-game-engine

I want my Android app to create a CSV file (including position, scale) and show cubes (made with the CSV file) through Unity.

This is my way of executing Unity project in Android:

I have done: (1) an Android project in Android studio and (2) a Unity project. (Unity project has a script to read CSV file and create cubes.)

In the Unity project, export the project using Android platform and the export project has assets folder, jniLibs folder, unity-class.jar file and UnityPlayerActivity.java file.

I copy these 4 components to the Android project. As a result, Unity project starts when I click a button in my Android app.

CSV file is saved in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{package name}/files/`.

Would you tell me how to read the CSV file by that path in Unity?

I used

```
if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.csv"))
  byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes
```

but didn't work.

I use Unity 2018.4.33f1 and Android Studio 4.1.3.

Comment: What exactly does `but didn't work.` mean? Getting any errors? Is the file just not found?

Comment: To debug for Android, use [`logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) with Android Studio. It should display any errors you are getting to the console.

Comment: Why would you read a csv as bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The if conditional path is wrong. You are right in using `Application.persistentDataPath`, but the correct path should be:

```
Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data.csv");
```

You do not need a trailing slash after the path. I would also consider using [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) instead of the `+` operator.

Comment: You **need** a trailing slash after the `persistentDataPath` .. that's basically what `Path.Combine` will insert... I agree though in general rather use `Path.Combine` for system paths

Comment: Oops messed up in my explanation. I'll leave the mistake with your comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use :

```
if(File.Exists( Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "data.csv")) 
    {
      //... Do Something
    }
```

But a better error-proof method would be to use Path.Combine().

```
if( File.Exists( Path.Combine( Application.persistentDataPath, "data.csv"))
    {
      //... Do Something
    }
```

Path.Combine() takes care of all the manual "/" you'll have to add.
It has upto 4 string overloads as well, for ease of access. So you can even do something like :

```
Path.Combine(String, String, String, String)    //Combines four strings into a path
```

Comment: What exactly would be the difference between `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "data.csv"` and OP's `Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.csv"` ? ;)